# Why isn't my function displaying data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.getData = function(time) {
    console.log(time + " get");
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/appointments',
        params: {
            time: time
        },
        headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'XXXXX',
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'XXXXX',
        }
    }).success(function(response, params, status, data, headers, config) {
        console.log();
        $scope.appts = data;
    }).error(function(params, status) {
        console.log(time + " eror");
    });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-view title="Appointments" right-buttons="rightButtons">
    <ion-content has-header="true" has-tabs="true" padding="true">
        <button class="button button-light" ng-click="getData()"> button-light </button>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in appts"> {{ appts.time }} </li>
        </ul>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Now according to the console, its working but its not displaying a list of the data.

Payload is this (just one for now) however... its still not showing the "time"

```
{
    "results": [{
        "createdAt": "2015-12-30T15:03:48.511Z",
        "objectId": "BjP1zZ8JqD",
        "time": "12:24",
        "updatedAt": "2015-12-30T15:03:48.511Z"
    }]
}
```

Comment: You need to format your code.  No one wants to read through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not accessing the data correctly,

First you do:

```
$scope.appts = data;
```

Which means to get at the first time you would need to access `results` first then the array then `time`

```
$scope.appts.results[0].time
```

What you probably actually want is

```
$scope.appts = data.results;
```

Since `results` is the actual array of data

Second you are using the wrong angualr expression

```
<li ng-repeat="item in appts"> {{ appts.time }} </li> </ul>
```

`appts` is the full array not one of the objects in the array, that would be `item`

```
<li ng-repeat="item in appts"> {{ item.time }} </li> </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't read  wrong you have the below response:

```
{"results":[{"createdAt":"2015-12-30T15:03:48.511Z","objectId":"BjP1zZ8JqD","time":"12:24","updatedAt":"2015-12-30T15:03:48.511Z"}]}
```

and in the HTML code you refer to appts.time, but you must refer to appts.results [0].time.